# Python sqlalchemy, найти совпадиние

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy

Привет, есть ли возможность отфилтровать массив?

допустим на входе есть, массив с именами `['barack', 'james']`
и в базе есть `user` с именем `barack`

можно ли както отфилтрировать? что то типо того
`User.query.filter(User.name == name)`, если есть совпадение, то вернуть обьект юзера.

Спасибо.

Comment: Найти вхождения, что ли? session.query(User).filter(User.name.in_(('barack', 'james'))).all()

Comment: Да, уже зделал, спасибо.